# How can i get every collection from every single document in firebase? (React)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So i have a post collection. Inside the "post" collection i have documents which has another collection called "likes".

So i want to get every single collection from every document at the same time and map them after. Is there a way to do that?

Because in Firebase you can only get a collection from just one document, but i want to get every collection from every single document.

Comment: Share your code

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand your question, you should use a Collection Group query. As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query), a "collection group consists of all collections with the same ID", i.e. `likes` in your case.

With such a query, you will get all the documents that are in all the `likes` sub-collections of all the documents in the `post` collection.

Comment: Hello @Magomed.Khamidov, did you have the time to look at the proposed solution?